# The identity element of $(\mathbb{N} , \gcd)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, semigroups, monoid

> Let $x*y= \gcd(x,y)$ on $\mathbb N$. I have to prove that $(\mathbb{N} , *)$ is a commutative monoid.

I knew how to show the associativity, but I have a problem on the identity element.

$\gcd(x,e)=x \to x\mid e$ so $e=xk,k \in \mathbb N ^*$

And I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: which natural number is a multiple of every natural number?

Comment: doesn't it go to infinity?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't contain any infinite quantities.  Second hint: There is sometimes a dispute about exactly what $\mathbb{N}$ comprises; in particular, there is a number that's sometimes counted as part of that set, and sometimes not.  What is it?

Comment: But infinity isn't a natural number.  Think about the other direction.

Comment: So every natural number is a multiple of 0? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: no, 0 is a multiple of every natural number, since $0*n=0$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

In this context, $0\in\Bbb N$. It is the identity because $0=n\times 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, *i.e.*, $n\mid 0$, hence $\gcd(n, 0)=n=\gcd(0, n)$.

The monoid is commutative because $\gcd(a, b)$ is $d$ such that $d$ divides both $a$ & $b$ and if both $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$, then $c\mid d$; so just swap $a\leftrightarrow b$ in the definition of $\gcd$ to get $\gcd(a, b)=\gcd(b, a)$.